# Im currently making a game with pygame and I need an explanation on some vector code

Tags: python, vector, pygame

So I'm making a game and I've got some help from another post to make bullets fly towards the mouse cursor. The original person who showed me this did explain it to me and I have a rough idea what it does but I didn't quite understand it. So I'm posting here for further explanation.

```
    def Shoot(self):
        pos = self.rect.centerx, self.rect.centery
        mpos = py.mouse.get_pos()
        direction = py.math.Vector2(mpos[0] - pos[0], mpos[1] - pos[1])
        direction.scale_to_length(10)
        return Bullet(pos[0], pos[1], round(direction[0]), round(direction[1]))
```

Edit: well I know what it does I just don't how I do it. I know It allows for projectiles to a fly towards the mouse even on diagonals but I don't know how it does it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whats happening is your getting the position of the cube/player with `pos`.

`mpos` is the mouse position on the screen

`direction` gets the direction between the player and the mouse. for example it the direction could be 10 pixels down and 100 pixels to the right.

[image: pic of maths]

The next line scales the direction down to 10, so instead of moving 100 pixels right and 10 down, its close to about 1 down and 10 right (not exactly but pretty close)

The last line creates the bullet with the x position, y position, x speed, y speed. rounding the speed as i said above, its not exactly 1 down and 10 right, it will be some decimal so to make it a nice number, you round it

Comment: Oh ok, thanks. I'm weird I don't like to add code I don't fully understand it feels like I'm cheating or something idk. Anyway thanks for the explanation :)

Comment: @TheBigKanuna hahaha hahaha. I might try AI later down the line when I'm better at coding :P

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to explain that in the answer to your previous question ([Im currently making a game with pygame and Ive run into an Issue.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61628416/im-currently-making-a-game-with-pygame-and-ive-run-into-an-issue)), but I'll try it again.

The instruction

> ```py
> direction = py.math.Vector2(mpos[0] - pos[0], mpos[1] - pos[1])
> ```

Computes the distance from the point `pos` (*A*) to the point `mpos` (*B*) along the x-axis and y-axis. Such a tuple of axis aligned distances is called [Vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_(mathematics_and_physics)):

[image]

At this point the [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) from point *A* to point *B* is unknown.

In the following the vector is scaled to a length of 10, by the operation [`pygame.math.Vector2.scale_to_length`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2):

```py
direction.scale_to_length(10)
```

That means that the x and y component of the vector is changed in that way (*xd, yd*), that the Euclidean length of the vector is 10 (*d = 10*):

[image]

If the components of the vector are added to the components of the point *A*, once per frame, then the point *A* steps towards the point *B* (*A1*, *A2*, ...):

[image]